# WKWebview is not retaining login cookie on App relaunch

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview

I'm using Native Google and Facebook login into my app, post the native login is successful, I send the accessToken/authCode to my server for server login as well, which in return sets a cookie in my WebView. This works absolutely fine, but when I close my app and relaunch it, for some reason my login cookie is not always retained, it's very random, sometimes my login cookie persists while other time, it doesn't.

I am pretty new to iOS development so I don't know many intricacies of it, but coming from Android where WebView automatically persists the cookie, I thought `WKWebView` would do the same, but it doesn't I guess. I looked upon many solutions on Stackoverflow, where I found about `NSHTTPCookieStorage` and `WKWebsiteDataStore` but I did not understand any of them, as to how they should be associated with the WKWebView and do I have to manually set those cookies or is there any configuration which automatically sets the cookie

```swift
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.preferences = wkPreferences
let navOffset = getNavigationOffset()
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                y: navOffset,
                                width: self.view.bounds.width,
                                height: (self.view.bounds.height - navOffset)),
                       configuration: config)
var UAString: String?
webView!.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent", completionHandler: {data, _ in
    UAString = (data as! String)
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        webView!.customUserAgent = getUserAgent(originalUA: UAString!)
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": getUserAgent(originalUA: UAString!)])
    }
})
webView!.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
webView!.scrollView.delegate = self
webView!.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "developerExtrasEnabled")
webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    webView.allowsLinkPreview = false
}
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
```

Looking for an answer, as I'm stuck in this issue for some time now, answer in Swift would be preferred

Comment: If you're using the default configuration, cookies should be persisted unless they expired.